# Sweet Alert briefly shown on Logout with React

Tags: reactjs, sweetalert

Working on my Logout function with react which:

1. clears local storage
2. clears the token
3. redirects to the home page
4. displays an alert

My sweet alert works, it just disappears very quickly. Here is the code for my Logout component:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert';
import { setToken } from '../api';

const Logout = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    setToken('');
    location.href = "/home/";
    <SweetAlert
  title="You are now logged out!"
  onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
  onCancel={this.onCancel}
  btnSize="sm"
/>
}

export default Logout;
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `location.href = ...` will reload the browser tab, so any component you render here will go away. (I'm guessing you wrapped your alert JSX in the `swal` function you've imported here if its showing up at all, but I don't see that in your example. [Looks like that's how it works](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-with-libraries)).

If you are using react router, something like `history.push('/home')` with [useHistory](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) instead would probably solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the method and was expecting a refresh of the page just like with location.href. I have looked at the doc but it doesn't specify the behavior when using history.